# http rest: Disadvantages of using json in query string?

Tags: json, rest, http, query-string

I want to use query string as json, for example: `/api/uri?{"key":"value"}`, instead of `/api/uri?key=value`. Advantages, from my point of view, are:

1. json keep types of parameters, such are booleans, ints, floats and strings. Standard query string treats all parameters as strings.
2. json has less symbols for deep nested structures, For example, `?{"a":{"b":{"c":[1,2,3]}}}` vs `?a[b][c][]=1&a[b][c][]=2&a[b][c][]=3`
3. Easier to build on client side

What disadvantages could be in that case of json usage?

Comment: The URL could become to long.

Comment: You're probably interested in this: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/270898/designing-a-rest-api-by-uri-vs-query-string The basic idea is that in a REST-based API, the resource should be mapped as cleanly as possible to the URI. I think putting JSON in the query string is quite the opposite of that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good if it's

```
/api/uri?{"key":"value"}
```

as stated in your example, but since it's part of the URL then it gets encoded to:

```
/api/uri?%3F%7B%22key%22%3A%22value%22%7D
```

or something similar which makes `/api/uri?key=value` simpler than the encoded one; in this case both for debugging outbound calls (ie you want to check the actual request via wireshark etc). Also notice that it takes up more characters when encoded to valid url (see browser limitation).

For the case of 'lesser symbols for nested structures', It might be more appropriate to create a new resource for your sub resource where you will handle the filtering through your query parameters;

```
api/a?{"b":1,}
```

to

```
api/b?bfield1=1
api/a?aBfield1=1 // or something similar
```

Lastly for the 'easier to build in client side', i think it depends on what you use to create your client, usually query params are represented as maps so it is still simple.

Also if you need a collection for a single param then:

```
/uri/resource?param1=value1,value2,value3
```

Comment: But `[` and `]` also escabed, so `?a[b][c][]=1&a[b][c][]=2&a[b][c][]=3` become `a%5Bb%5D%5Bc%5D%5B%5D=1&a%5Bb%5D%5Bc%5D%5B%5D=2&a%5Bb%5D%5Bc%5D%5B%5D=3`, so, both variants are unreadable.

Comment: On what particular case would you need the brackets? if your resource requires a collection as a param isnt not represented by `/api/uri?param=value1,value2,value3`?

Comment: of course, just a single collection could be represented byt that syntax. But, for example, there is an issue, if param need to cointain "," symbol, so, there should be some escaping. Brackets need to define nested structures, which are not list, or list of structures. But main advantage of json is simplicity for end user: you don't have N rules, one for collection, one for structure, custom escaping and etc. Just `json_encode` or `JSON.stringify` your php array/js object and pass it as query string. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: As mentioned in my original example, nested structures are to be handled as a different resource. and in cases where your param requires a `,` then that's where escape characters comes into play. If you would want a pretty formatted json, then i would suggest change it it POST and let it be a payload (like elasticsearch). Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: It is not aways possible to handle complex query as nested resource. For example, I want to implement pattern-matching list filtering. So, I pass structure, as a query to resource, which returns list of entities. Query structure describes *shape* of result entities. I can find out how nested resource fits to that case.